# как вставит ссылку на свое приложение до публикации его Play market в этот же приложение?

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play-console

У меня есть приложение не  опубликованное в Google Console.Но сейчас на этапе написания приложения я реализовал кнопку share,через который пользователь может поделиться скриншотом из приложения и я туда же хочу добавит ссылку на это же приложение.Как быть если я еще не опубликовал это приложение и не получил ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vashe.prilozhenie
```

где com.vashe.prilozhenie - идентификатор вашего приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки есть в двух форматах:

```
# http - позволяет выбрать, где открыть:
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
# открыть страницу приложения в Google Play:
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

Например, `market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps`

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#UriSummary)

Comment: как я понимаю ссылку можно формировать и без публикации в play market . да?

Comment: Это ровно та ссылка, которая у вас будет после публикации. Можно.